# ValidationError(PodDisruptionBudget.spec)

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, configmap

while helm upgrading the prometheus, I am receiving the below error.

***Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(PodDisruptionBudget.spec): unknown field "enabled" in io.k8s.api.policy.v1.PodDisruptionBudgetSpec***

can someone pls help with the solution.... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Most likely caused by charts versions mismatch.

> helm -n $NS upgrade --install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus -f /PATH/TO/values.yaml --version $YOUR_VERSION

Comment: how to fix this? am using prometheus 2.34 and always getting this error with the upgrade commands.